# Difference between Amazon RDS and Wamp server's MySql database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS, recently I have launched a windows server instance successfully and install Wampserver on it as well PhpMyAdmin within it. my question is that if I have already installed MySQL by Wampserver, so is there any difference between the Amazon RDS database instance and PhpMyAdmin database.

Comment: Focus in one question for post.

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is merely a mysql client. You can probably point your existing phpmyadmin install at an RDS Mysql instance and it would work just fine. [From the RDS for Mysql page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) you can see the major difference *"Amazon RDS for MySQL frees you up to focus on application development by managing time-consuming database administration tasks including backups, software patching, monitoring, scaling and replication."* With your current setup, you own the entire stack, but with RDS you just button click your way to a live database, backups, monitoring, etc

Comment: thanks, @JNevill I do appreciate your help, it's clear my doubts ...Thanks again :)